# passing a value in anchor tag to another jsp

Tags: jsp, parameters, anchor, href

i have a jsp in which ther are some anchor tags for redircting to other html pages or jsps.. but one particular jsp, i wanna send a parameter ie.. username to the jsp..from this jsp.. how can i do it in a simple way.. or any way possible
i want to send uname parameter that i am obtaining from scriptlet to the jsp savingsAccount.jsp when it is clicked on

```
div class="bar">
 <div class="menulink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
            <div class="menulink"><a href="savingsAccount.jsp">Savings</a></div>
            <div class="menulink"><a href="#">FAQ</a></div>
            <div class="menulink"><a href="#">Help</a></div>
            </div>

    <% 

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mutualfund", "root", "");


    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
    out.println(uname);
    out.println("Editing "+uname);
    String query="SELECT * FROM `cust_info_table` WHERE `cust_id`=\""+uname +"\"";
    ResultSet resultset =  statement.executeQuery(query) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div class="bar">
 <div class="menulink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
            <div class="menulink"><a href="savingsAccount.jsp?username=<%=request.getParameter("uname")%>">Savings</a></div>
            <div class="menulink"><a href="#">FAQ</a></div>
            <div class="menulink"><a href="#">Help</a></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And in the `savingsAccount.jsp` you can get this parameter using:

```
String uname = request.getParameter("username");
```

Comment: its going to savingsaccount true... but unfortunately username is taking null i mean request.getParameter("username") ; is giving null value!!! meaning thevalue is not taken

Comment: its taking null because this `request.getParameter("uname")` is null most probably. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

In jsp page

```
<a href="viewProfile?email=<%=request.getParameter("email")%> " >View Profile</a>
```

In java page

```
   @RequestMapping("/viewProfile")
    public void viewUser(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){

        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        System.out.println(email);
    }
```